# .htaccess url redirect and append .html only to asp pages

Tags: .htaccess

I am archiving a dynamic site by localising it into a static version and hosting it in a subfolder of a new domain.

http://oldsite.com/main.asp to
http://newsite.com/v4/main.asp.html

There was plenty of documentation explaining how to make a redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^oldsite\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://newsite.com/v4/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But I'm struggling to work out the grep for adding `.html` to any file ending in `.asp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code you posted works except for the issue with the filename extension, then you can simply modify it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.org\.org$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp$ https://example.org/v4/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```

This obviously does not handle any query parameters. But that won't work anyway when turning a dynamic site into a static one as you try, so I assume that simply does not matter...

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers host configuration instead of using .htaccess style files. Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks! Luckily for me the old site doesn't have any directories (ie, oldsite.com/products) so this works fine but imagine it wouldn't work for all circumstances. Also, another tip I've picked up while doing this - use 302 redirects and incognito browsing to avoid browsers rightfully remembering a permanent redirect.

Comment: Ah, the root is a directory so I just added the original rewrite underneath your suggestions and the rules cascade - if you keep the L flag.

Comment: I don't see any issues with a folder in the request path, that should be handled without issues. The only situation where an additional rule is required is if you have a request _not_ ending in the file extension handled.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was meaning. Going to oldsite.com/ didn't work but when I added the original rule it did.